# Triggering a Jenkins Pipeline job from a Bitbucket repository

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket, bcbsn

This is a direct continuation of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39768919/how-to-trigger-a-jenkins-pipeline-from-a-bitbucket-repository), not asked by me, whose purpose was to hook up Bitbucket with Jenkins so that a repo change would trigger a Jenkins Pipeline job.

The issue here is the accepted answer, while likely correct, deals with a service of Bitbucket (called Services) that is getting removed in favor of their Webhooks service. I am trying to get one pipeline job to run two freestyle jobs in parallel (both unit tests) that need to be run on the one branch when a push is made.

**How can a Pipeline job be triggered by a push to Bitbucket using Webhooks instead of Services**?

As an addendum; the [Bitbucket Build Status Notifier Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Bitbucket+Cloud+Build+Status+Notifier+Plugin) is NOT compatible with pipeline jobs, hence the need to find a workaround. I'm open to workarounds that don't follow the linked question's strategy as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to trigger a jenkins pipeline from a bitbucket repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39768919/how-to-trigger-a-jenkins-pipeline-from-a-bitbucket-repository) -> If it is related to the first question, please add a comment on the answer you got, but please don't create another question for this.

Comment: @Pom12 The original was not posted nor answered by me - I was under the impression hijacking others' posts was frowned on? If that's wrong I can take that approach instead, but I have no way of getting the original poster to change their question to suit my modified query. As I indicated in my question, I need the same result, but using a different service, so the method should by definition be different.

Comment: This is open ticket in Jenkins: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-38447